# Identification of Iguanodon and Maiasaura

Tags: fossils

What are some good ways to distinguish between Iguanodon and Maisaura fossils, or even just pictures of the two dinosaurs?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to distinguish iguanodon from maiasaura is to look for iguanodon's hands, which are very peculiar indeed. The hand has five digits. The thumb has a large, prominent spike on it for defensive purposes. The three middle fingers are fused and end in hoof-like nails for walking on all fours. The fifth digit corresponding to our little finger sticks out at an angle from the others and is flexible. It is believed that this enabled it to gather food. It is apparent from these strange forefeet or hands that iguanodon, a herbivore, often stood upright like a biped.